# Find Unmatched records in joined table

Tags: sql

Let me explain the scenario to you. We have two tables, people and points, which are as follows.

`People: Id, FirstName, LastName, Birthday(YYYY-MM-DD)`

`Points: Id, PersonId, Score, Description`

`Points` table refers to the `People` table by `PersonId` foreign key.

Our system automatically scores people on their birthdays, but sometimes there may be a problem and the system may not score. I need the `SQL` query to be able to identify which people did not score on their birthday.

I wrote the below query to find birthdays but I couldn't find out how to detect people who didn't get scores on their birthdays.

```
DATEADD(Year, DATEPART(Year, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(Year, BirthDate), BirthDate)
BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(WEEK, -1, GETDATE())) AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Comment: please tag the appropriate database.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: The points table has no date column so how do you know when a score was created, and therefore whether scoring happened on someone’s birthday? Or do you just mean whether a person has a record in the points table, regardless of their birthdate?  Or are you just comparing the month/day of their birthday to today - so anyone with a birthday prior to 16 Feb, regardless of year, should be scored?